# Where can I ask agriculture-related questions? And will there be a site on SE for them?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a list of questions that are not a good pure fit to any existing site I know of on Stack Exchange.

The area is agriculture, farming, precision ag.

Is there a chance that such a site will be added?

How should I ask questions related to this topic on existing sites?

Comment: I once proposed Agriculture and Agronomy but it couldn't survive. If you have a solid group we can try once more :)

Comment: As a farmer, I really wish that such a thing existed. It might take a while to get going, but it could be really amazing.

Comment: I'm in. I'm setting up a homestead and SE would make a better forum. Also earth science/ag, gardening, or mechanics aren't the same spread of topics as a farm, or the right group of people to tell you where all the zerk fittings are on an implement when the manual is poorly written.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is [agriculture tag](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agriculture) on [Earth Science.SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/):

> The cultivation of food and materials, specifically from or derived from plants and animals using traditional or modern industrial practices.

There is also an <strike>active proposal</strike> [now-deleted proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/103884/agriculture-farming). You can follow and support proposals by posting example questions, voting on existing example questions, and most crucially, inviting more people to follow it. (When it will reach 60 followers and 40 questions with a 10+ score it will move to the next phase.)

Comment: How about cooking.SE and Biology.SE?

Comment: @Remi.b not really, as it's not about cooking or biology as far as I can tell.

Comment: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

As of 2020-05-10, there are questions tagged agriculture on:

1. Worldbuilding (133 questions)
2. Mi Yodeya (101 questions)
3. History (74 questions)
4. Earth Science (43 questions)
5. Biology (40 questions)
6. Skeptics (37 questions)
7. GIS (26 questions)
8. Economics (25 questions)
9. Open Data (23 questions)
10. Politics (16 questions)
11. Sustainable living (11 questions)
12. Veganism & Vegetarianism (9 questions)
13. Law (8 questions)
14. Internet of Things (3 questions)
15. Quantitative Finance (1 question)
16. Ask Patents (1 question)

There have been attempts to start a dedicated site via Area 51, but these have failed.

If you are interested in all aspects of agriculture, you can [follow this tag filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/384965/agricultural-questions) that I created for agricultural questions across the entire Stack Exchange network.  See [tag-filters](/questions/tagged/tag-filters).

[image: Agriculture questions]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to share on [Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/).

In case you don't know if your question fits the community:

[What topics can I ask about?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> - the general care and feeding of plants;
> - gardening problems such as diagnosis and management of plant diseases and pests or methods for controlling weeds;
> - identification of plants — trees, shrubs, flowers, wildflowers — cultivated or growing in the garden or as a houseplant, or of animals that are affecting your garden or houseplants;
> - plant recommendations;
> - garden or landscape planning and layout;
> - the practice of gardening, including timing, tools and techniques.

Note that one should avoid these questions (the emphasis was mine):

> - the culinary uses of herbs/fruits/plants (try Cooking instead);
> - the health and nutritional aspects of fruits/vegetables;
> - plant biology, beyond what is generally gardening knowledge (try Biology instead);
> - the framing, plumbing or electrical aspects of building greenhouses, decks, or other structures (try Home Improvement instead);
> - **large scale agriculture and/or the business of gardening.**

[Here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags) one is able to see the relevant tags.

Comment: Good that you edited your answer, but it's best deleted, seeing that OP asks specifically about Agriculture, and precision Agriculture, that is something that isn't done small-scale or at home. It's purely professional and thus off-topic at Gardening & Landscaping

Comment: @Luuklag the question is "Where can I ask agriculture-related questions? And will there be a site on SE for them?". In the question text the OP mentions "agriculture" and "farming", apart from "precision ag". Therefore, and considering that some agriculture questions are on-topic in this community, I do see this answer being relevant.